# Find element by XPath isn't working in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find a  element in selenium with this XPATH `/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div/input`.

I copied it from inspect element, and copy xpath. I saw that some persons with the same problem use "*" character but I don't know where I should to use it.

this the html code

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: CorpItem.Name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
                                                class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ..." required="required">
```

Here is my code on Selenium

```
  IWebElement corpName = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div/input"))
```

Comment: give example html and example code, it's easier to work with, and someone will reply.

Comment: I edited the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath

```
//input[@type='text'][@class='form-control']
```

In your code you used XPath and gave selector as CSS. Please verify.

Using your XPath, your code must be

```
IWebElement corpName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div/input"))
```

If it didn't work, try

```
IWebElement corpName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='text'][@class='form-control']"));
```